# How to sort MNIST digits into each class label?

Tags: python, keras, mnist

I'm importing mnist dataset from Keras using `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()` and what I want to do is sort each sample by it's corresponding digit. I'm imagining some trivial way to do this but I can't seem to find any label attribute of the data. Any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`y_train` and `y_test` are the vectors containing the label associated with each image in x_train and x_test respectively. That will tell you the digit shown in each image. So just get the indices that will sort these vectors using `np.argsort` and then use these indices to re-order the corresponding matrix.

```
import numpy as np

idx = np.argsort(y_train)
x_train_sorted = x_train[idx]
y_train_sorted = y_train[idx]
```

So if you want all the images for a particular digit, you can simply grab them by indexing the corresponding matrix

```
x_train_zeros = x_train[y_train == 0]
x_train_ones = x_train[y_train == 1]
# and so on...
```

Notice that in this case you don't need to pre-sort the data.

Comment: Thank you for very concise and helpful solution! Works like a charm :)