# How to select a specific number of each class from the MNIST dataset

Tags: python, keras, mnist

I'm using tensorflow to work on Mnist. I need to train my network with a specific number of data of each class (for example 500 number of sample of each digit).
I've found [how to sort the DB with class labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52618700/how-to-sort-mnist-digits-into-each-class-label).

```
idx = np.argsort(y_train)
x_train_sorted = x_train[idx]
y_train_sorted = y_train[idx]
```

but how can I select 500 number of each one and then combine them and the shuffle?

Answer (score 1):

If you have all in one `DataFrame` then you can `groupby` label and then get `head` or `tail`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
    'X2': [21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32],
    'label': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c']
})

groups = df.groupby('label')

df2 = groups.head(2)    
#df2 = groups.apply(lambda x:x[:2]) # the same as head(2)
#df2 = groups.apply(lambda x:x.sample(frac=1)[:2]) # shuffled before get values

print(df2)
```

Result

```
   X1  X2 label
0   1  21     a
1   2  22     a
4   5  25     b
5   6  26     b
8   9  29     c
9  10  30     c
```

And after that you can shuffle it and split it into `X_train`, `y_train`

```
df2 = df2.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

X_train = df2[['X1','X2']]
y_train = df2['label']

print(X_train)
print(y_train)
```